# Is it possible to let gcc 4.7 and gcc 4.8 co-exist in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: installation, 64-bit, gcc, c++

I have some development work, it seems that GCC 4.8 will not work well with other development tools, so I may have to stick with GCC 4.7, but I am not sure if this is allowed in Ubuntu 13.10(64bit). If yes, can anyone tell me how to install and configure gcc 4.7 here?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the two versions will happily coexist. You can invoke each individually by specifically invoking it though only one version will have `CC` aliased to it.

Install each separately with:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.7

sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8
```

When you are ready to compile with a specific version invoke it explicitely:

```
gcc-4.7 source.c -o executable
```

or

```
gcc-4.8 source.c -o executable
```